# VK Login error while logging in through application and not webView Dialog

Tags: android, json, logging, fingerprint, vk

Good day.I have an issue with a alraedy released social network application where users will not be able to login through VK application.The issue is that i get the json error where VK pretends the error to be the sdk fingerprint error.I have searched a lot,and anything i found was related to the actual hash key/ssha fingerpring key and package name.Hurry to tell you everything is set up fully correct as if i have no VK application isntalled on the phone the login going through perfectly without any issue,but if i install the VK application and try to login through my application within the VK application it throws the json error of fingerprint,so i have no clue what VK developers did and try to do,but if someone can help me it will be great!

Here is how i initialize the VK inside the application tag.

```
   VKAccessTokenTracker vkAccessTokenTracker = new VKAccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        public void onVKAccessTokenChanged(@Nullable VKAccessToken oldToken, @Nullable VKAccessToken newToken) {
            sharedHelper.putVkAccessToken(newToken.accessToken);
        }
    };
    vkAccessTokenTracker.startTracking();
    VKSdk.customInitialize(this, appId, sharedHelper.getVkAccessToken());
```

And whenever i need to login user through the VK i call the simple method like this

```
 VKSdk.login(this, vkScopes);
```

but the json issue inside the application of VK just killing me.Please help me to solve the issue if it is the issue on my sied.

Answer (score 0):

I have been faced with this weird problem for some days, until I found the probable solution.

Open your android.manifest file and put the following intent filter into activity (activities) in which VK authorization call is used, or activity (activities) that contain fragment(s) in which VK authorization call is used:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="vk1234567" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Replace `vk1234567` with your VK application's id, and two letters "vk" should be at the beginning of the id as well.

Also FYI, SHA-1 fingerprint that signs your APK should be specified in VK application console without `:` commas and spaces.